# Why using googletest PrintToStringParamName() to print test suffix not working?

Tags: c++, googletest

I wanna google test to show different suffix in parametrized test, my code is as following:

```
class CacheTestP
    : public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::string>
{

};

TEST_P(CacheTestP, NewTest)
{
}

vector<string> GetStrings()
{
    vector<string> ret;
    ret.push_back("Insert"s);
    ret.push_back("Query"s);
    return ret;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(Prefix, CacheTestP, ::testing::ValuesIn(GetStrings()), testing::PrintToStringParamName());
```

It seems that the function `PrintToStringParamName()` convert the std::string `Insert` into `\"Insert\"`, which is weird, because in their source code they clearly wrote:

> // The last argument to INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P allows the user to specify
> generator and an optional function or functor that generates custom test name
> suffixes based on the test parameters.

> // testing::PrintToStringParamName is a builtin test suffix generator that returns the value of testing::PrintToString(GetParam()).

So what did I do wrong? I think it supposes to work regarding to their comments.

Comment: For distinguishing between numbers and strings containing numbers as texts in outputs.

Comment: @S.M. Could you elaborate it more and explain why?

Comment: For distinguishing number 1 and string "1" in outputs.

Comment: @S.M. why? I do not need any number in my test name suffix, so why should I care about that?

Comment: This is an opinion based answer. Welcome to gtest authors and ask your question there.

Comment: @S.M. I have. I got what you mean, but I do not think this is an opinion based answer, because they clearly use a `ÙniversalTersePrinter<T>::Print()` function, so it meant to be universal and I wanna know why it does not fit the requirement.